# Hazelcast IMap#get periodic extreme latency

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are experiencing very inconsistent performance when doing an `IMap.get()` on a particular Hazelcast map.

Our Hazelcast cluster is running version 3.8, has 8 members, and we connect to the cluster as a Hazelcast client. The map we are experiencing problems with has a backup count of 1.

We've isolated the slow operation to single `IMap.get` operation with logging on both sides of that line of code. The `get` normally takes milliseconds, but for a few keys it takes between 30 and 50 seconds. We can do numerous `get` operations on the same map and they all return quickly except for the same few keys. The particular map is relatively small, only about 2000 entries, and is of type `<String,String>`

If we restart a member in the cluster, we still experience the same latency but with different keys. This seems to indicate an issue with a particular member as the cluster re-balances when we stop/start a member.  We've tried stopping each member individually and testing but experience the same symptoms with each member stopped in isolation. We’ve also tried reducing and increasing the number of members in the cluster but experience the same symptoms regardless.

We've confirmed with thread dumps that the generic operation threads are not blocked and have tried increasing the number of operation threads as well as enabling parallization but see no change in behavior.  We've also enabled diagnostic logging in the cluster and don't see any obvious issues (no slow operations reported).

Looking at Hazelcast JMX MBeans, the maxGetLatency on the particular map is only about 1 second, much lower than what we are actually experiencing. This seems to indicate an issue with the client connection or underlying network. However, the number of slow keys is only about 1% of the total keys, so unless we are way out of balance, the issue again doesn't seem to be with a single member as you would expect about 1 in 8 keys to be slow.  We've also confirmed from the Hazelcast logs that the cluster is stable. Members are not dropping out and rejoining.

Interestingly, if we stop and restart the whole cluster, we get good performance initially but after a few minutes it degrades back to the same state where a few specific `IMap.get` operations take 30+ seconds.

This exact code is not new and has been running just fine for quite a while. However, once this behavior started, it is consistently reproducible here. As far as we know, there have been no environmental changes.

Is there any diagnostic logging we can enable to get insight about the Hazelcast client? Are there any other diagnostic options available to track down where this latency is coming from?  Unfortunately we are not able to reproduce this in any other environment which does seem to point at something either environmental or something unique to the cluster in this environment.

One other potentially interesting thing is that we see the following log statement every 6 seconds in each of the cluster members. The "backup-timeouts:1" is concerning but we aren't sure what it means.

`INFO: [IP]:[PORT] [CLUSTER_NAME] [3.8] Invocations:1 timeouts:0 backup-timeouts:1`

Any ideas or suggestions on how to debug this further would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please confirm that no other applications are running in the server boxes? Also, are you running the cluster on VMs or bare-metal? You can use the following properties to enable diagnostics on client: `-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true` and 
`-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.metric.level=info`

Comment: The cluster is running on VMs and there are not any other applications running there. Both the VMs and the JVM processes are running in their normal ranges for all the basic metrics like memory and CPU usage.

Comment: Can you please check if vMotion (https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmotion_datasheet.pdf) is enabled on your VMs? If so, can you disable it and try again? Also, can you please share GC logs if you have?

Comment: @nolt2232, did you ever try Alparslan's recommendation to disable VMotion?

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasted from https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7689

*InvocationFuture.get() has a built-in timeout when remote node doesn't respond at all. It doesn't wait forever. That timeout is defined by system property hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis.
When remote node doesn't respond in time, invocation fails with OperationTimeoutException.

Those timeouts are generally because of network problem between caller and remote or system pauses due to high load (GC pauses, OS freezes, IO latency etc).

You can decrease hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis to a lower value and enable diagnostics reports to see detailed metrics of the system.*

```
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.metric.level=info
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.invocation.sample.period.seconds=30
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.pending.invocations.period.seconds=30
-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.slowoperations.period.seconds=30
```

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#diagnostics

In my case the cause is waiting on incoming tcp connections on the host.